# UDim2.new(a, b, c, d) is acting very strangely

Tags: gui, lua, roblox

I am using a debugger and `(i-1)*50` is equal to `50`, but `UDim2.new(s.Position.Width, s.Position.X, s.Position.Height, (i-1) * 50)` is equal to `{0, 0}, {0, 0}`.

This makes no sense.

Here is the code:

```
local SoundButtonTemplate = script.Parent.Sound:Clone() -- This is a Frame, not a Sound.
script.Parent.Sound:Destroy()
[...]
game.ReplicatedStorage.ThisIsWhatYouCanDo.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(soundArray)
    [...]
    for i, sound in soundArray do
        local s = SoundButtonTemplate:Clone()
        s.GamepassId.Value = sound["GamePassId"]
        s.Text = sound["Details"].." (ID: "..sound["SoundId"]..")"
        s.Parent = script.Parent
        s.Position = UDim2.new(s.Position.Width, s.Position.X, s.Position.Height, (i-1) * 50)
    end
end)
```

Comment: Interesting. So you say that if you create a new local variable, assign `(i-1) * 50` to it and then pass that variable as the 4th parameter to `UDim2.new` then the code behaves differently?

Comment: @Philipp I have checked and even if I put the modified value in a variable and then use the variable as the 4th parameter it still returns 0 regardless of the variable.